# error: '...' is not a prefix unary operator

Tags: swift, for-loop, operator-keyword, prefix

Code:

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
for name in names[...2] {
    print(name)
}
```

Error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:3:19: error: '...' is not a prefix unary operator
for name in names[...2] {
```

I am new to swift so any relevant link or any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Using swift 4

Comment: That is valid in **Swift 4**. Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: You can do this only in Swift 4. In Swift 1-3 `...` and `..<` are infix only operators.

Comment: Compiles and runs in Xcode 9 beta 2, using Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin and others have said, this is valid in Swift 4. In earlier versions, you might wanna use this:

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
for name in names[0..<3] {
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: OP claims to be using Swift 4.

Comment: Yes, but since he said its not working, I am assuming he's actually using a lower version of Swift, possibly unknowingly (his code compiles perfectly without any edits for Swift 4), so maybe this could help in such a case.